# Draw tool in Texture Paint is not working

Tags: texture-painting

Draw in texture paint is not working. All of the other tools like spill and mask work but draw has no effect on the map or the model.

I did open a new file to test my work and on the new file the draw tool works correctly.

I created a new object in the same file and the tool, again did not work.

[image: Texture Paint]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many image nodes do you have for this material and which one is selected, cause that is the one that will displayed in solid view mode?   Based on these screenshots I don't really have enough to go on.

Comment: I added pictures of my nodes. What other pics would help?